# GA Tracking code on ajax requests?

Tags: ajax, tracking, google-ads-api

I have this:

```
<!-- Google Code for Tilmeldinger nyhedsbrev Conversion Page -->
<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ /
var google_conversion_id = 982857669;
var google_conversion_language = "da";
var google_conversion_format = "1";
var google_conversion_color = "ffffff";
var google_conversion_label = "e90GCIP3jwMQxe_U1AM";
var google_conversion_value = 0;
if (20) {
google_conversion_value = 20;
}
/ ]]> */
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js">
</script>
<noscript>
<div style="display:inline;">
<img height="1" width="1" style="border-style:none;" alt="" src="http://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion/982857669/?value=20&label=e90GCIP3jwMQxe_U1AM&guid=ON&script=0"/>
</div>
</noscript>
```

I inserted it on the page the ajax request to, and in the response I see this script^.

But it does not track or count anything?

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script's not being executed when the AJAX request returns. You can either try and figure out why, or I think the `<noscript>` bit does most of the work anyway so you could try removing the rest and just placing the image into your page:

```
<img height="1" width="1" style="border-style:none;" alt="" src="http://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion/982857669/?value=20&label=e90GCIP3jwMQxe_U1AM&guid=ON&script=0"/>
```

This should issue an image request that sends the tracking data to AdWords.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the GA event's tracking. Here is all info you need: http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/eventTrackerGuide.html

I suggest you to write small function:

```
  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-xxxxxxxx-x']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

  function event(category, action, label, value) {
    _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', category, action, label, value]);
  }
```

And jsut call event() function.